# I can't install "bind9-dnsutils" in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bind

While I'm try to install `sudo apt-get install bind9-dnsutils` , I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bind9-dnsutils : Depends: bind9-libs (= 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2) but 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

so, I have to install `bind9-libs` , when I try to install `sudo apt-get install bind9-libs`  , I get the following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bind9-libs is already the newest version (1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I need `bind9-dnsutils` for installing `nslookup`.

How Do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version of `bind9-libs` (1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.4) is [not present in ubuntu 20.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/bind9-libs) so you have done something strange in order to get it.

You should check that your /etc/apt/sources.list, sources.list.d and PPAs don't include anything unexpected. `apt policy bind9-libs` may show where you got it from.

Ultimately you'll be wanting to remove it and get `bind9-libs` version 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3 installed.